# What is the select mode and when is it relevant to use it?

Tags: visual-mode, history-of

I accidentally pressed `gh` in normal mode and started a selection, so I looked up the doc and found [`:h Select-mode`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/visual.txt.html#Select%2Dmode).

From what I understand the select mode is close to the visual mode excepted that:

- Typing a printable character, `<CR>` or `<BS>` will delete the selection, start insert mode and replace the selection with the input.
- `hjkl` and other normal or visual mode movement won't extend the selection unless they're prefixed with `<Shift>`
- `<CTRL-O>` and `<CTRL-G>` will switch to visual mode.
- The doc also says the following, which if I understand correctly means that it is possible to do linewise selection which are then treated characterwise:

  > When using an operator in Select mode, and the selection is linewise, the
  >   selected lines are operated upon, but like in characterwise selection.  For
  >   example, when a whole line is deleted, it can later be pasted halfway a line.

I am a little confused because I don't understand why this mode was created: all I can see is that it is less convenient than visual mode and doesn't provide more features.

Also, the searches that I have made all give results about doing selection in visual mode but do not treat select mode.

So my questions are:

- Why was the select mode created?
- What are its advantage compared to visual mode?
- What is a use case where it is more interesting to use select mode?

**MetaNote** I have no idea which tag is relevant to this question, feel free to retag if needed.

Comment: To me, this sounds like what you'd expect from most GUI editors. (Selecting a line doesn't mean that it will go to a new line when pasting, shift+arrows extend it, typing replaces selection, all what I'd expect from, say, notepad).

Comment: @muru: I agree that it reminds of this kind of editor but does it means that this mode would have been implemented just to please some users who would want to use Vim as a poor text editor? That seems pretty weird to me actually.

Comment: actually, that pasting property is useful in some cases. I'm sure someone has posted a question about pasting like that here. And as for overwriting, that saves a keystroke (you don't have to press `c`), so depending on what you want to do, select mode could be useful. Pity I keep forgetting about it.

Comment: I'll try to find this question then. For the overwriting I don't really feel like the `c` is a saved keystroke because the selection is not as convenient as in visual mode (since you can't use `e` or `iw` directly).

Comment: Also, I think, but am not sure, that mouse selection used select mode.

Comment: You're right: when `'selectmode'` contains `mouse` and `'mouse'` contains a flag for the current mode, selecting with the mouse will start select-mode (according to the doc).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The whole point of select mode is to provide a selection behavior similar to the one used in conventional editors.

On the same note, there's [mswin.vim](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/mswin.vim) which changes a bunch of options and mappings to make Vim feel like a conventional editor.

I can only assume those were added to please a subset of Vim users, probably at the time Vim was ported to Windows (I can feel some disdain for Windows in the doc).

Anyway, select mode is essential to snippet expansion plugins and can be abused for fun and profit:

```
nnoremap § *``gn<C-g>
inoremap § <C-o>gn<C-g>
snoremap <expr> . @.
```

Comment: I think it is pretty surprising to port Vim on Windows and to create this kind of mode to please the users: If they wanted a "classical" editor why would they use Vim then? But it seems to be the only explaination so... Also I don't really understand the profit of your mappings: as far as I understand they select the word under the cursor in select mode, once you've done that why is it useful?

Comment: Once the word is selected, type something then press `§` to select the next occurrence, type something else then press `§` again to select the next occurrence, and so on. You can press `.` to repeat the last insertion. It's a variant of "the dot formula".

Comment: I still don't get it. In what way is the selection behavior more like conventional editors?

Comment: @still_dreaming_1, in a conventional editor, type `foo` and select it. You don't need press any key to replace what was selected, do you? That's what select mode emulates.

Comment: @romainl what is that "double S" character you are typing? How do you type that character?

Comment: @Michael It's a [section sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_sign). How you type it depends on your keyboard layout and operating system, but e.g. on the Apple keyboards for many (most?) languages it's above the `Tab` key.

Comment: @Rich it doesn't exist on a US keyboard, I have never seen that symbol...having its name though let me lookup how to type it in Mac OS though, alt-6, §...tks!

Comment: @Michael Glad I could help! If you're remotely interested in Apple's keyboard layouts you can see them all on [their keyboard localizations page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201794).

Comment: I can't decide what's more interesting: the really great key bindings that you provided as an example, or the fact that some keyboards come with a builtin section symbol!  (Also, it's great to know that <C-g> can switch between `visual` and `select` modes.)

Comment: What does `@.` do? According to help, this seems to be playing back the macro in the `.` register. Is it being set somehow? OK: I found out: it `Contains the last inserted text`. So then the snoremap will cleverly make `.` paste the last inserted text over the active selection.

Comment: @StevenLu yes, you read it right.