# In visual mode, how do I bind a key so that the selected text generates "%s/<SELECTEDTEXT>/<CURSORHERE>/g"?

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, command-line, replace

In visual mode, how do I bind a key so that the selected text generates

```
%s/<SELECTEDTEXT>/<CURSORHERE>/g
```

?
Preferably `;` considering I never use it otherwise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
xnoremap ; y<Esc>:%s/<C-R>"//g<Left><Left>
```

- `xnoremap` visual mode mapping, non-recursive

  - `vnoremap` includes select mode as well, see [What is the select mode and when is it relevant to use it?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4891/what-is-the-select-mode-and-when-is-it-relevant-to-use-it)
- `;` key to be mapped
- `y` yank the selected text
- `<Esc>` visual mode to normal mode
- `:%s/` substitute command, all lines as range
- `<C-R>"` paste contents of selected text
- `//g` rest of substitute command
- `<Left><Left>` move cursor to the left twice

Comment: better to use xnoremap

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt done, searched about differences and added a link to select mode...