# custom mapping not working with yank command

Tags: key-bindings

This can be super simple stuff but i am not able to figure it out, i have to mappings in my config file

```
nnoremap gh ^
nnoremap gl g_
```

These mappings work just fine and behave as expected when i use them in normal mode, but as soon as i combine them with yank command like `ygl` to yank the text from cursor to last non-white space character and same way `ygh` to first non-white space character, it simply does not work.

Am i missing something here ?

Answer (score 1):

Mappings are of different types. The ones you have mapped are `normal mode` mappings. And the ones that you claim not to work are `operator-pending mode` mappings. I suggest you take a look at `:h vim-modes`.

So, put these in your $MYVIMRC, to get operator-pending mode mappings, to work as you asked:

```
onoremap gh ^
onoremap gl g_
```

Notice, the only change is the letter `o` from `n` which, unsurprisingly, indicates `operator-pending mode` while `n` indicates `normal mode`.

For better flexbility, I suggest you also map visual mode mappings, like this:

```
xnoremap gh ^
xnoremap gl g_
```

These will work when you are in visual-selection mode. **Note** that, there are two kinds of mappings in `visual mode` mappings, visual mode and select mode. And I suggest, you nearly always use select mode mappings with letter `x` in your config. If you want to know more, [here is a q/a thread](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4891/what-is-the-select-mode-and-when-is-it-relevant-to-use-it).